# Make large CSV changes with PHP

Tags: php, csv

I will first explain my issue... I have a CSV file that is imported onto my server daily.

I am then wanting to import the contents of the CSV file onto the Magento platform as products however my CSV file is not set up correctly for a Magento import.

So here are the first 2 rows of my CSV:

```
Feed_Id,Vehicle_ID,FullRegistration,Colour,FuelType,Year,Mileage,Bodytype,Doors,Make,Model,Variant,EngineSize,Price,Transmission,PictureRefs,ServiceHistory,PreviousOwners,Category,FourWheelDrive,Options,Comments,New,Used,Site,Origin,v5,Condition,ExDemo,FranchiseApproved,TradePrice,TradePriceExtra,ServiceHistoryText,Cap_Id,AttentionGrabber
119345,679049,VO10OHS,BLACK,Diesel,2010,77000,Estate,5,AUDI,Q7,3.0 TDI QUATTRO S LINE 5d AUTO 240 BHP 0% FINANCE ,2967,24495,Automatic,"http://static.click247.co.uk/vehicles/679/679049/large1/3672310.jpg,http://static.click247.co.uk/vehicles/679/679049/large1/3672315.jpg,http://static.click247.co.uk/vehicles/679/679049/large1/3672316.jpg,http://static.click247.co.uk/vehicles/679/679049/large1/3672317.jpg,http://static.click247.co.uk/vehicles/679/679049/large1/3672313.jpg,http://static.click247.co.uk/vehicles/679/679049/large1/3672312.jpg,http://static.click247.co.uk/vehicles/679/679049/large1/3672314.jpg,http://static.click247.co.uk/vehicles/679/679049/large1/3582603.jpg,http://static.click247.co.uk/vehicles/679/679049/large1/3582604.jpg,http://static.click247.co.uk/vehicles/679/679049/large1/3672321.jpg,http://static.click247.co.uk/vehicles/679/679049/large1/3672322.jpg,http://static.click247.co.uk/vehicles/679/679049/large1/3582591.jpg,http://static.click247.co.uk/vehicles/679/679049/large1/3582592.jpg,http://static.click247.co.uk/vehicles/679/679049/large1/3582673.jpg,http://static.click247.co.uk/vehicles/679/679049/large1/3582605.jpg,http://static.click247.co.uk/vehicles/679/679049/large1/3582593.jpg,http://static.click247.co.uk/vehicles/679/679049/large1/3582594.jpg,http://static.click247.co.uk/vehicles/679/679049/large1/3582597.jpg,http://static.click247.co.uk/vehicles/679/679049/large1/3582606.jpg,http://static.click247.co.uk/vehicles/679/679049/large1/3582598.jpg",Y,0,CARS,Y,"Adjustable Steering Column/Wheel - Rake/, AUDI MUSIC INTERFACE, AUDI PARKING SYSTEM, BLACK STYLING PACK, BOSE SURROUND SOUND, ELECTRIC TAILGATE, HDD-BASED SATELLITE NAVIGATION SYSTEM, MOBILE PHONE PREPARATION, PEARL EFFECT PAINT, PRIVACY GLASS, SMART BEAM, STAINLESS STEEL RUNNING BOARDS, VUSIBILITY PACKAGE, Air Bag Driver, Air Bag Passenger, Air Bag Side - Driver/Passenger, Alarm , Anti-Lock Brakes, Armrest - Front/Rear, Ashtray/Lighter, Bumpers, Central Door Locking - Remote , Centre Console, Centre Rear Seat Belt, Child Locks - Electric, Cigar Lighter, Climate Control, Computer - Driver Information System, Cruise Control, Cup Holder, Electric Windows - Front/Rear, Electronic Brake Force Distribution, Electronic Stability Programme, Front Fog Lights, Head Air Bags - Front/Rear, Head Restraints - Front/Rear, Heated Rear Screen, Immobiliser, In Car Entertainment - Radio/CD, Mirrors External - Electric Heated/Foldi, Mirrors Internal - Auto Dimming Rear Vie, Parking Aid - Rear, Power Sock",Comprehensive RAC  parts and labour warranty available on selected vehicles-FINANCE AVAILABLE on selected vehicles-Call 01204 393181 for more details. Please click on the Dealers Website link to view more details and larger photos. REF:KEZW,N,Y,C,UK,Y,,,,0,,Full Dealer,,MEGA SPEC OVER £8000 EXTRAS
```

It might be best to copy and past the CSV data and save it as a CSV to understand the issue further.

If you look at column 16 you will notice there are a bunch of URL images separated by commas however are inside some quotes.

I would like to take the first URL image inside the quotation marks and put this into an extra column within that row.

I'd like to do this for every row that is in the CSV apart from the first row.

Any idea if this is possible with PHP and if so could you show me an example of how this might be done?

Much Appricated

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php (and http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php), http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

Assign value to $file_locatoin and try the following.

```
<?php
        $final_csv = array();
        $file_location = 'your_csv_file.csv';//assign your csv path here
        $file = fopen($file_location, "r");
        //get the file header/column name
        $file_heading = fgetcsv($file);
        //set a new column nanme as new_column
        array_push($file_heading,'new_column');
        //assign header for final csv
        array_push($final_csv,$file_heading);

        while (!feof($file)) {
            $row_data = fgetcsv($file);
            //get 16 number column
            $column = $row_data[15];
            $image_url = explode(',',$column);
            $first_img = $image_url[0];

            array_push($row_data,$first_img);
            array_push($final_csv,$row_data);
        }
        //var_dump($final_csv);
        fclose($file);


        convert_to_csv($final_csv, 'new.csv', ',');

        function convert_to_csv($input_array, $output_file_name, $delimiter)
    {
        /** open raw memory as file, no need for temp files, be careful not to run out of memory thought */
        $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
        /** loop through array  */
        foreach ($input_array as $line) {
            /** default php csv handler **/
            fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter);
        }
        /** rewrind the "file" with the csv lines **/
        fseek($f, 0);
        /** modify header to be downloadable csv file **/
        header('Content-Type: application/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $output_file_name . '";');
        /** Send file to browser for download */
        fpassthru($f);
    }
?>
```

Comment: I seem to be getting these errors when using this and no file is created:

Comment: Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /home/nickmadd/public_html/csv-convert.php on line 19

Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in /home/nickmadd/public_html/csv-convert.php on line 35

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/nickmadd/public_html/csv-convert.php:19) in /home/nickmadd/public_html/csv-convert.php on line 40

Comment: make sure your csv path is correct and use the same csv which you are share with your above question? i tested it with your above csv and it's work fine.